# Have Jest a method like the "when" in mockito framework test?

Tags: typescript, mocking, mockito, jestjs

I need to mock a class from a route with Jest in typeScript, I found the "when" method with the mockito framework, would the jest have any one with the same purpose?

Comment: Could you please explain what `when` does or what you try to archive.

Comment: basically what I need to know is when the test is calling a function or class and at that point I need to call a mock to resolve a "fake payload"

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature build in into jest. I can imagine some ways to get the same result by:

1. put the logic into your mock:

```
const spy = jest
   .spyOn(myObject, 'do')
   .mockImplementation((someNumber)=> someNumber > 1? true : false)
```

2. have a series of return values so you could test the cases after each other

```
const = jest
  .spyOn(myObject, 'do')
  .mockReturnValue(true)
  .mockReturnValueOnce(false)
  .mockReturnValueOnce(true);
```